# Visual Studio 2017 - Not Able to see Publish Profiles

Tags: visual-studio-2017, web-deployment, pubxml

In my VS 2017, my publish profile is not being listed in the publish section of the VS 2017.

I can run the application with no error but I can't publish it or see and log file saying any error about when I do right click the project and click on publish. And also even if I wanted to create new profile VS just doesn't open create new profile window.

Any guess what might be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Can you open the files themselves using a text editor? If so, do they look well-formed?

Comment: I put it on one of the XML validators on the web looks good, I just take it out the lines that I added to encrypt my web.config file. Now when I right click and publish I can see my profile but still can't see PublishProfiles under Properties in solution explorer @MikeB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like @MikeB said, I checked that with XML validators on the web but then realized the problem was that I was using invalid XML tag and XML attributes in `.pubxml` after using the correct one problem was solved!

Check whether you are using your XML node and attributes correctly!

Answer (score 2):

I've recently encountered this problem in VS 2019 with a project whose `.pubxml` profiles had been working fine and have not changed for quite a while.

The problem turned out to be a corrupted `.pubxml.user` file that was preventing VS from loading any profiles. The `.pubxml.user` files exist in the same directory as the `.pubxml` file and deleting them solved the issue for me.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. One of the .pubxml has conflict, after resolving the conflict(SVN) it worked.